# Metric spaces Lipschtiz mapping proof

Tags: metric-spaces

Prove that the map $f : R^2 → R$ ,  $f(x, y) = 2 \sin x − y$  is a Lipschitz mapping with
Lipschitz-constant $2\sqrt{2}$. You can use the fact that $\sqrt2\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} ≥ |a| + |b|$

So if f(x,y) is continuously differentiable then by mean value theorem $\frac{|f(x) − f(y)|}{|x − y|}= |f'(t)|$ for t between x and y. Let $k= \max|f'(t)|$ Then

$$\big|f(x) − f(y)\big| ≤ k|x − y|$$ so k is a lipschitz constant

so $\frac{∂f}{∂x}=2\cos x$ so $f'(t)=2 \cos t$

So by MVT for $a,b \in f(x,y)$ we have

$|2\cos(t)| = \frac{|f(a) - f(b)|}{|a - b|}$

So $|f(a) - f(b)|=|2\cos(t)||a - b|\le 2|a - b|\le 2(|a|-|b|)\le 2\sqrt2\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$ using the triangle inequality and then the fact given above.

Comment: Here's a [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please share your thoughts on your problem so far. If you don't show any effort, usually neither will we.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the map $f$ is $C^1$, its Lipschitz constant is bounded above by the supremum of $\|\nabla f\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.* As you note, $f_x = 2\cos(x)$. Also, $f_y = -1$.

So estimate:
$$\|\nabla f\| = \sqrt{4\cos^2(x) + 1} \leq \sqrt{5}.$$

Since $5<8$, so $\sqrt{5}<2\sqrt{2}$, which means $2\sqrt{2}$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$.

---

*This is because you can estimate $|f(p) - f(q)|$ by integrating $\nabla f$ over the line segment connecting $p$ and $q$.